# Android - YouTube API get videoId from video list

Tags: android, json, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get videoId in (items:[ id:{ ) but it shows org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId.
Is there any wrong code here?

```
items: [
{
    kind: "youtube#searchResult",
    etag: ""etag"",
    id: {
        kind: "youtube#video",
        videoId: "nsVttBhYM2E"
    },
    snippet: {
        publishedAt: "publishedAt",
        channelId: "channelId",
        title: "title",
        description: description",
    thumbnails: {
        default: {
            url: "thumbnail url",
            width: 120,
            height: 90
        },
        medium: {
            url: "thumbnail url",
            width: 320,
            height: 180
        },
        high: {
            url: "thumbnail url",
            width: 480,
            height: 360
        }
    },
    channelTitle: "channelTitle",
    liveBroadcastContent: "none"
    }
},
```

This is part of source code get video id from video list

```
JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject json_data = items.getJSONObject(i);
    strVideoID = json_data.getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId");
}
```

Comment: How get json from youtube...?

Comment: i am also working on this kind of project...

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer,  but it may help someone in future.

First check if "kind" equals to "youtube#video", then try to get the "id" string. Both the key are in the "id" JSONObject.

As the response may also contain some playlists,  instead of "videoId" there may be "playlistId".